# Highlighting Duplicate number 20 in excel only when they are adjacent

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a Excel 2013 column where I need to highlight duplicate number 20
but only when they are next to each other:

```
211
20<-- this should be highlighted
20<-- this should be highlighted
52
20<-- this should be highlighted
2​0<-- this should be highlighted
20<-- this should be highlighted
925
8745
20 <-- this should not be highlighted
33
```

I tried Conditional Formatting but it wont work.

Any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: What do you mean by highlight?  Simply changing text color, you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=AND(A2=20,OR(A1=20,A3=20))
```

1. Select all the cells that you want to have the rule
2. Click on `New Rule` under `Conditional Formatting`
3. Enter the formula in the formula box (see screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dave! This CF solution worked for me.